# Why async/await variable return undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

Below is my code...

```
async function getItemDetalil(url) {
  const $ = await request(url, (err, res, body) => {
      return cheerio.load(body);
  });
  console.log($);
}
```

Why my '$' is undefined?
I assume it will be a cheerio object?

Comment: *"I assume it will be a cheerio object?"* Why do you assume that? Have you read the documentation of `request` of looked at its implementation? The function probably returns `undefined`. You cannot use `await` to magically get the return value from the callback. The function you `await` should return a promise. It would only be cherrio object **iff** `request` actually returns a cherrio object or a promise that resolves to a cherrio object.

Comment: Have you tried using a `var` or `let` instead of a `const`?

Comment: Is `(err, res, body) => {
      return cheerio.load(body);
  }` a callback function? Can you include full text of `request` at Question?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I try and still return undefined

Comment: @guest271314 Yes of course it is, it's a function passed as a callback to another function.

Comment: What makes you think `request` returns a promise?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, though is that fact obvious to OP?

Comment: Magic, of course.

Comment: You are probably looking for [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/218196)

Answer (score 2):

> Why async/await variable return undefined?

`await x` evaluates to the value of `x` or, if that value is a promise, to the value the promise resolves to.

Example:

```js
// Value
(async function() {
  console.log('Normal value', await 42);
}());

// Promise resolution
(async function() {
  console.log('From promise:', await Promise.resolve(42));
}());
```

If `$` is `undefined`, then `request()` either returns `undefined` or a promise that resolves to `undefined` (unlikely). Have a look at its documentation or source code to find out what exactly is happening.

---

> I assume it will be a cheerio object?

It would only be cherrio object **iff** `request` actually returns a cherrio object or a promise that resolves to a cherrio object.

[How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/218196) might help you to solve your actual coding problem.