# Variable is undefined after async IIFE

Tags: javascript, async-await, iife

```js
  let groupedWishlistProducts;

  (async function () {
      groupedWishlistProducts = await fetchGroupedWishlistProducts();
      console.log(groupedWishlistProducts); // logs returned value properly
  })();

  console.log(groupedWishlistProducts); // logs undefined
```

Why is `groupedWishlistProducts` undefined on global, even if I have initialized in global scope?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why async/await variable return undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715291/why-async-await-variable-return-undefined)

Comment: Sorry, no. I'd like to know the order of execution for each steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's undefined because you havn't assigned anything to it (yet).

The order that things get executed is:

1. Declare the variable
2. Declare and begin executing the IIFE
3. Call fetchGroupWishlistProducts
4. Having reached an `await`, the IIFE now returns to the outer code.
5. Log groupedWishlistProducts (outside the function)
6. Some time later, the promise from fetchGroupedWishlistProducts resolves, and the async function resumes
7. Assign the result of fetchGroupedWishlistProduct's promise to groupedWishlistProducts
8. Log groupedWishlistsProducts (inside the function)

Comment: #4 Should read *"Due to the async, the IIFE now returns a promise"*

Comment: I'm describing the order things happen, so #4 is describing *when* it returns. The `await` keyword is what causes it to return at that time, as opposed to another time. I've reworded it to emphasis the time, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

`async function` returns `Promise`, so by the time you execute IIFE, the Promise is still pending, as the result `fetchGroupedWishlistProducts()` would not be resolved. So in your case, second `console.log` will be executed first, and is `undefined`

To handle this, you could wrap it into another IIFE

```
let groupedWishlistProducts;

(async function() {
  
  await (async function () {
    groupedWishlistProducts = await fetchGroupedWishlistProducts();
    console.log(groupedWishlistProducts); // logs returned value properly
  })();

  console.log(groupedWishlistProducts);

})()
```

or just resolve the promise

```
let groupedWishlistProducts;

(async function () {
  groupedWishlistProducts = await fetchGroupedWishlistProducts();
  console.log(groupedWishlistProducts); // logs returned value properly
})().then(() => {
  console.log(groupedWishlistProducts);
})
```